# grouper day and cumsum speed

Tags: pandas, datetime, group-by, cumsum

I have the following df:

[image]

I want to group this df on the first column(ID) and on the second column(key), from there to build a cumsum for each day. The cumsum should be on the last column(speed).
I tried this with the following code :

```
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df = df.sort_values(['ID','key'])
grouped = df.groupby(['ID','key'])
test = pd.DataFrame()
test2 = pd.DataFrame()
for name, group in grouped:
            test = group.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='1d'))['Speed'].cumsum()
            test = test.reset_index()
            test['ID'] = ''
            test['ID'] = name[0]
            test['key'] = ''
            test['key'] = name[1]
            test2 = test2.append(test)
```

But the result seem quite off, there are more rows than 5. For each day one row with the cumsum of each ID and key.

[image: 2nd output of grouper and cumsum]

Does anyone see the reason for my problem ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Friendly reminder, it's useful to include a runable example

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{"cid":33613,"key":14855,"ts":1550577600000,"value":50.0},
        {"cid":33613,"key":14855,"ts":1550579340000,"value":50.0},
        {"cid":33613,"key":14855,"ts":1550584800000,"value":50.0},
        {"cid":33613,"key":14855,"ts":1550682000000,"value":50.0},
        {"cid":33613,"key":14855,"ts":1550685900000,"value":50.0},
        {"cid":33613,"key":14855,"ts":1550773380000,"value":50.0},
        {"cid":33613,"key":14855,"ts":1550858400000,"value":50.0},
        {"cid":33613,"key":14855,"ts":1550941200000,"value":25.0},
        {"cid":33613,"key":14855,"ts":1550978400000,"value":50.0}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'], unit='ms')
```

I believe what you need can be accomplished as follows:

```
df.set_index('ts').groupby(['cid', 'key'])['value'].resample('D').sum().cumsum()
```

Result:

```
cid    key    ts        
33613  14855  2019-02-19    150.0
              2019-02-20    250.0
              2019-02-21    300.0
              2019-02-22    350.0
              2019-02-23    375.0
              2019-02-24    425.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```